# How to toggle one value of a data attribute with multiple values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, attr

I am able to toggle a single data-attribute

```
<div data-state="one"></div>
<a href="#">Toggle</a>
```

like this

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
$('div').attr('data-state', $('div').attr('data-state') == 'one' ? 'two' : 'one')
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/3e4s8tyL/)

My question is, if I have a data-attribute with an array of multiple values like this:

```
<div data-state='["one","three"]'></div>
```

How can one toggle just one value, i.e. "one" to "two", with leaving "three" unchanged.

Comment: Can you explain expected behaviour? What do you mean by `toggle just one of those values`?

Comment: In the single attribute example, clicking 'a', toggles data-state from 'one' to 'two' back and forth, I want the same behavior of this toggle when the data-state contains multiple values. I don't want to remove 'three' when the toggle of one to two occurs. See edit

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    var state = $('div').data('state').split(',');

    $('a').on('click', function(){
         $('div').attr('data-state', state[0] == 'one' ? 'two' : 'one'
    });
```